# XML Conversion with XSLT with quotes

Tags: xml, xslt

We are trying to convert the XML output of a scan job that is done in ECopy Share Scan. The XML File looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <index id="FileNameField.eCSWHCRequest">eCSWHCRequest</index>
  <index id="FileNameField._">_</index>
  <index id="FileNameField.Date>08012015"</index>
  <index id="Submission By">Josh McMinn</index>
  <index id="Department">Admin</index>
  <index id="Submission Date (mm/dd/yyyy)">08/01/2015</index>
  <index id="Submission For">iPad</index>
  <index id="Total Cost">850</index>
</data>
```

I cannot figure out how to bring out the individual index IDs and change what they are called.

The desired output looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<data>
  <eCSWHCRequest>eCSWHCRequest</eCSWCRequest>
  <FileNameField>_</FileNameField>
  <Date>08012015</Date>
  <SubmissionBy>Josh McMinn</SubmissionBy>
</data>
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you explain the hidden logic? Your output doesn't have some elements transformed from your input. On what basis are you omitting those?

Comment: Thanks Michael, that worked exellent.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example to get you started:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/data">
    <xsl:copy>
        <eCSWHCRequest>
            <xsl:value-of select="index[@id='FileNameField.eCSWHCRequest']"/>
        </eCSWHCRequest>
        <FileNameField>
            <xsl:value-of select="index[@id='FileNameField._']"/>
        </FileNameField>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your example input (after correcting it to be well-formed XML!), the **result** is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
   <eCSWHCRequest>eCSWHCRequest</eCSWHCRequest>
   <FileNameField>_</FileNameField>
</data>
```

**Note:**
`</eCSWCRequest>` does **not** close `<eCSWHCRequest>`. You can't get sloppy when dealing with XML, it's very unforgiving.